ipad external keyboard switching between layouts stopped working after update to 18.1
My Ipad pro updated itself to the latest ios version 18.1, which introduced a problem using multiple keyboard layouts. I have an apple external keyboard (en-us layout). Before the update, I could easily switch between different layouts by pressing the `Globe' button. I often need to switch between en-us, swedish and greek, sometimes all three within a few sentences.
After the update, there are 'multi-lingual' keyboards, but I can't get this to work. So far, even getting swedish to work failed (even without being able to switch). When in the settings I only have a swedish keyboard (after deleting all the ohters), the en-us layout of the external keyboard is used anyway. Note that the 'software keyboard' on the screen does switch to the swedish layout, but I need to be able to use the external keyboard, using different layouts.
I tried google and searched this site, but that didn't help. Any feedback, hits etc. would be greatly appreciated!

To be sure I understand: the external keyboard is separated from the iPad, not a Magic Keyboard cover, correct? In any case, the physical keys will obviously be in US-EN but you want them to respond as using the SWE layout. You mentioned it working before 18.1. Have you tried a Forced Restart?

Try going back to monolingual keyboards.  Instructions at  https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250009074

@TomGewecke, thanks, this is actually precisely what I did, but it doesn't work. When I add two momolingual keyboards, the symbols I get when using the swedish layout, are those from the US-EN layout

@NotationMaster I should have been clearer, it is a Magic Keyboard. As you said, the physical keys are in US-EN, but I want them to respond as using the SWE layout (for instance). I tried the Forced Restart, but that didn't solve the problem.

I wonder if it may be a problem with iPadOS. Do you have a Mac handy to try if this works as you expect it to?

@NotationMaster I connected the iPad to my macbook pro, which seems to work as expected. Is there something special I should check? If I connect the magic keyboard to my macbook, it doesn't seem to work as an external keyboard, but I don't think that's what you had in mind.

@NotationMaster After one of the resets, the option 'Hardware Keyboard' appeared under Settings > General > Keyboard. There, I could change the setting for 'Swedish', from 'Automatic - U.S.' to 'Swedish', which solved the problem. Not sure why this option appeared all of a sudden (the keyboard was connected all the time), and why the Swedish keyboard was set to 'Automatic - U.S.' but in any case, the problem is solved now. Thanks for your time!

@TomGewecke see my last comment to NotationMaster. Thanks for your time.

After a few (not sure how many) Forced Restarts, the following option in Settings appeared:
Settings > General > Keyboard > Hardware Keyboard
There, one can change the settings for the keyboards that are added.
Make sure that setting for say the 'Swedish' keyboard is actually 'Swedish' and not something like 'Automatic - U.S.'
Edit: it was pointed out in the comments that this is a very common problem, and not related to the update per se, see this discussion.

Normally the Hardware Keyboard settings are available any time the hardware keyboard is connected.  Having them wrong by mistake is a very common problem, the fix is described at https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250006655

@TomGewecke thanks for pointing out that this is a general problem, and not related to the update per se.
